# Compiler error after upgrading to Xcode 4.6 using setDataSource

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4.6

I was upgrading some projects to use Xcode 4.6 and Clang LLVM compiler but I'm getting stuck with an error. I'm not the biggest obj-c geek so I'm a bit stuck here. I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687224/data-sources-and-nstableview) touches base with my problem but doesn't quite give me a solution.

My class derives from NSTableView (`@interface MyClass : NSTableView`) but when I make the following call:

```
[self setDataSource:self];
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id<NSTableViewDataSource>' with an lvalue of type 'MyClass *'
```

Using Xcode 3.2.6 had no issues with this call but now I'm stumped as to why I'm getting an error. I do add some table columns previous to this call and set some attributes but essentially I get the error from the call above.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your class doesn't appear to implement the data source protocol.

Answer (score 0):

For one, your table view should **NOT** be its own datasource. This breaks the [MVC model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) that Cocoa uses. Views should only be concerned about displaying/presenting data, it should not store the data (that's the model's job) nor should it be the class that interfaces the view with the model (that's the controller's job).

Usually the datasource will be a `NSViewController` that conforms to the `NSTableViewDataSource` and the  protocol:

```
@interface MyViewController : NSTableViewController <NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Is this possible to do without adding new classes and interfaces possibly?

Comment: At the bare minimum, you must implement the `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol. I would very much recommend refactoring your architecture though. It is currently broken and make your code less reusable, and harder to debug and harder to test in isolation. Better to nip it in the bud now than to let it fester.